# Categorize based on first 3 characters in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame in R that is like the following:

---

variable1....  variable2

ab1_2......... 123

cde_1..........456

fgh_1..........789

ab1_1......... 012

fgh_2..........345

---

I am trying to make a new column that assigns a value (or variable) based on the first 3 characters of variable1. So something like this:

---

variable1....  variable2....  variable3

ab1_2......... 123.............1

cde_1..........456.............2

fgh_1..........789.............3

ab1_1......... 012.............1

fgh_2..........345.............3

---

Does anyone have any tips on how I can accomplish that?

Thank you for your help in advance.

Calvin

Comment: You can use `substr` to split off the first three characters into a new column. Then you can simply set `as.factor` and you don't even need to refactor to numeric unless you want to.

Comment: Have a look at `?substr` and try `transform(your_data_frame, variable3 = substr(variable1, 1, 3))`.

Comment: For example if you want numeric levels `as.numeric(as.factor(c("test", "stuff", 'stuff')))`

Comment: Thank you for the prompt replies Mako212 and Tino. I saw that post earlier and didn't think about using as.factor afterwords. Thanks again!

Comment: `data$var3 = factor(b<-sub('_.*','',data$variable1),d<-unique(b),1:length(d))`

Comment: Hi Onyambu,

Sorry, I'm still new to manipulating data with R. Do you mind explaining (or pointing me to) what that means?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this out and let me know -

```
#This is your table, original_data, I made so I can test my code
original_data<-data.frame(Variable1=c("ab1_2","cde_1","fgh_1","ab1_1","fgh_2"),variable2=c(123,456,789,012,345))

#This extracts the first 3 letter and creates a new column with only these 3 letters
original_data<-cbind(original_data,join_column=substr(sample$Variable1,start = 1,stop=3))

#This is the data that contains which 3 letters correspond to which number
join_data<-data.frame(join_column=c("ab1","cde","fgh"),assigned_number=c(1,2,3))

#Finally you join and Voila!
final_data<-merge(original_data,join_data,all.x = TRUE)
```

Comment: You should note that this is just but an example. OP might have a data worth thousands of rows

Comment: The join will handle thousand rows. At some point OP will have to create a table like this(which is essentially a case-when statement) if there is no logic in assigning the number to the first three letters.

Comment: Hi Mohit, thank you for your reply. Yes that is fairly straight forward. I was also wondering if there is a function or a way of coding it so that it recognizes patterns by itself? I think that I could use the assign or gsub functions, but not too sure about how to actually use it.

Comment: There is a logical pattern followed try running `data$var3 = factor(b<-sub('_.*','',data$variable1),d<-unique(b),1:length(d))` and you will see the pattern